# What does StringTokenizer(str," .,?!"); function do?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I was wondering what does the following function do for the following input:

```
String s=" HELLO!THIS IS A TEST.OK?";
StringTokenizer stk=StringTokenizer(s," .,?!");
```

And also, can anyone explain about this function too?
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to understand the tokenization concept first 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization

Also read Java docs
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: As Mohsen writes - please try to understand the concept of tokenization and then read the JavaDoc for StringTokenizer.
If you then run into problems, you can ask questions which are more specific and easier to answer for us :)

Comment: @Mohsen Thank You so Much!!
JesperBangsholt I just have basic idea about StringTokenizer and wasn't understanding this part(i had seen this in some program). BUt thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringTokenizer` is used to split String into *tokens*. It allows you to provide a set of *delimiters* during creation time.In your case, you are creating a StringTokenizer instance with delimiters (space,dot,comma,question mark,exclamation).this will split the input string by using any of the delimiters provided.Please read the java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score -1):

StringTokenizer breaks your string into several pieces depending on what you give as the second argument. It breaks the first string whenever any of the characters of the second string is found.

So for your case you will get these strings after tokenizing:

```
["HELLO", "THIS", "IS", "A", "TEST", "OK"]
```

Comment: He's asking *how*, not what it outputs.

Comment: "what does the following function do for the following input" sounds like asking _what_ to me. None of the other answers tell _how_ it works, either.

Comment: I already have edited my answer to explain things. And I added output just because example teaches much better than explanation